# TypeScript не поддерживает import js файлов?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babel

Вот такая вот штука - воспользовался [TypeScript-Babel-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter),
Все шло хорошо, пока не появилась необходимость за`import`мить js класс.

Получаю ошибку:

> *src/index.ts(1,20): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './Cosmos'. 'C:/WWW/TypeScript-Babel-Starter/src/Cosmos.js'*

Что в таком случае принято делать? Как вы поступаете, если есть необходимость работать с js файлами в ts?

Comment: мне кажется тут ошибка с путями файла

Comment: Нет, это babel упирается в то, что подключаемый файл не имеет .ts расширение. Но, в целом, логично что будет ошибка при подключении - это ожидаемо, иначе теряется вся суть  ts. Но вопрос в том, что если js подключать можно, то  - как?

Answer (score 3):

Компилятору нужно передать **--allowJs** в качестве аргумента, или в файле **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html